# Replace textbox value into DataGridView in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Why I can't replace the textbox value into DataGridView..Here I just want to edit that specific cell only..unable to remove and add edited text into datagridview...

AccountInfo.txtPrtflDscrptn.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value.ToString

```
    If AccountInfo.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
           DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex)
          DataGridView1.Rows.Insert(AccountInfo.txtPrtflDscrptn.Text)

    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If AccountInfo.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then

  DataGridView1.item(colomnindex,rowindex).Value = AccountInfo.txtPrtflDscrptn.Text

 End If
```

you can give value of colomnindex and rowindex

Comment: its working but the edited value add on cell (0), I need to add the edited value on the specific cell. DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value.ToString..

Comment: please elabotrate ur requiremnt

Comment: Actually I just need to edit on pecific cell only which is like "DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value.ToString"..I able to select and edit the specific cell value from another textbox but unable to replace the value into DataGridView. "DataGridView1.item(colomnindex,rowindex).Value = AccountInfo.txtPrtflDscrptn.Text" here I able to replace the value in DataGridView but not on the specific cell..So, how to give value in colomnindex and rowindex? Thanks

Comment: here ....your colmnindex will be 2  and rowindex will be DataGridView1.CurrentRow.index